# Emulate simple VBA macro to be compatible with Google Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets-macros

How can I convert this simple VBA to Google Sheets?

```
Sub SELECT()

Dim Cval As Variant
Cval = Sheet4.Range("A16").Value
Sheet4.Range("D1:T" & Cval).Select

End Sub
```

I keep getting errors while trying to use this macro in Google Sheets and I cannot find the issue.

The code I'm currently working on in Google Sheets:

```
function SELECTIE() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var Cval = spreadsheet.getRange("A16").Value
  spreadsheet.getRange("D1:T" & Cval).activate();
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the errors and the lines that cause them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one minor issue.

In the first statement, you're getting the `spreadsheet` object, but you need the `sheet` object. So `getSheets()[0]` will get you the first worksheet.

```js
function SELECTIE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  var cVal = ss.getRange('A16').getValue();
  ss.getRange('D1:T' + cVal).activate();
}
```